# Current date and time is not inserting in table by this query

Tags: mysql, node.js

```
var currentDate=new Date().toLocaleString().slice(0,10);

var now = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();

if(data = true){

con.query('INSERT INTO rooms (user_id,current_date,current_time) VALUES (?,?,?)',[user_id,currentDate,now],function(error,results,fields){
                    if(error) throw error;
```

this error occur: 
MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'current_date,current_time

Comment: The simplest solution is simply to avoid using reserved words as identifiers.

Comment: Also, save yourself a world of pain... Store date and time as a single entity

Answer (score 3):

current_date and current_time both are reserved functions and keywords in MySQL

- [current_date](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_current-date)
- [current_time](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_current-time)

You can use different names of columns then these names, OR you can use backticks to escape column names:

```
'INSERT INTO rooms (`user_id`,`current_date`,`current_time`) VALUES (?,?,?)'
```

Also, MySQL has inbuilt functions to get current date and time:

See: CURDATE() CURTIME() & NOW() - together date and time.

Comment: This seems more apt... https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html#keywords-5-5-detailed-C

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the exact cause of your error, but MySQL's date/time API actually provides functions which can be used to access the current date and time.  SO the following should work here:

```
var sql = 'INSERT INTO rooms (user_id, `current_date`, `current_time`) ';
sql += 'VALUES (?, CURRENT_DATE, CURRENT_TIME)';
con.query(sql, [user_id], function(error, results, fields) {
    if(error) throw error;
});
```

As a side note, why are you storing the date and time in separate columns?  This is something which usually should only be done if there be a very compelling reason for doing so.  Otherwise, just store date and time together in a timestamp or datetime column.